# Postgres tech role for sequence only

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, database-sequence

There is role sequence_owner. This is special tech role for working with sequence only.

```
create role sequence_owner;
GRANT sequence_owner TO administrator;
GRANT USAGE, SELECT, UPDATE  ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA schema1 TO sequence_owner;
```

Also there are several users with role `administrator`: user1,...user42

```
GRANT administrator TO user1;
GRANT administrator TO user42;
```

Using user1 I can create sequence:

```
create sequence schema1.test_sequence;
```

but I can't change owner to special `sequence_owner` role

```
alter sequence schema1.test_sequence owner to sequence_owner;
```

There is error:
ERROR: permission denied for schema schema1

I don't wont to use:

```
GRANT CREATE, USAGE ON SCHEMA schema1 to sequence_owner
```

Because in this case this role `sequence_owner` will have more priviligies than it must have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-altersequence.html

**It's impossible:**
You must own the sequence to use ALTER SEQUENCE. To change a sequence's schema, you must also have CREATE privilege on the new schema. To alter the owner, you must also be a direct or indirect member of the new owning role, and that role must have CREATE privilege on the sequence's schema.